# gcc / (g)as ignore breakpoint trap (x86)

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

I've written a C program which includes some assembler code in which I have some instructions which lead to a breakpoint exception (`INT3`) This is nice when debugging (since you don't have to save and restore the breakpoints when restarting the gdb session).

But now I want to disable these traps, which is possible by the `-no-break` or the `-no-trap` option of `as` (the gnu assembler), but I don't find a way to specify these options as options of `gcc` so that `gcc` passes the option down to as.

Is there a way to do so? (somehow `gcc -g -o file -Xassembler -no-trap main.c file.S` does not work)

Comment: Should be `-Wa,-no-trap`.  Refer to the manual for details.  Note that this option doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Perhaps define `int3` as an assembler macro that expands to nothing, as a way to disable it.  Or a CPP macro since you're using `.S`:  `gcc -Dint3=''  file.S main.c`

Comment: Is by `--break or --no-trap (also synonyms, and the default) take a break exception.` meant, that a break exception is thrown otherwise when a multiplication overflow happens? (this line was, why I thought this might make `as` ignore breakpoint traps)

Comment: Actually this (`gcc -Dint3='' file.S main.c`) seems to be really smooth. If there is no native way to disable `breakpoint traps` I'd accept this as an answer ;)

Comment: @atticus As the manual states, this is a MIPS specific option.  I suppose it changes the instructions generated for multiplication mnemonics.  It has nothing to do with x86 and likely does not affect code generation on x86 in any way.  As Peter Cordes says, using a preprocessor macro is a good way to achieve the desired functionality.